# Selecting text in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have two textview and I want to implement the textselection feature in both the textview. The Api version is 15 and above. the xml for both the textview is same.
In my code, I have called the method,

```
tv1.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
});

tv2.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

});

When I run the code, I am successfully able to select the first textview but not able to select the second textview. Getting the logcat message as Textview is not selectable, action mode is cancelled. I have gone through all the links but not able to resolved the issue.

The xml structure for both the textview is same.

I have also added the:
tv1.setTextIsSelectable(true);
tv2.setTextIsSelectable(true);

Comment: Have you try to set  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
} yet?

Comment: I tried that too but of no use. I am just confused as its working for the first textview correctly but not for the second textview. For second textview, always getting the message as textview is not selectable....

Comment: I have tried and tested it, both textviews work perfectly fine. Maybe you need to clean your project and rebuild it. Try to use LinearLayout to test again, avoid using RelativeLayout. Take a try and let me know the result, hope it works.

Comment: Hi.. I have tried that but still not able to get the setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback for the second textview....For the first textview its working fine....getting issue with the second textview only....

Comment: Thanks user2652394....I gone through the documents and found that I was using setMovementMethod for the second textview due to which the focus from the second textview is lost. Now the problem is resolved....